# How do I simulate this post request in C#

Tags: c#, .net, post, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I need to send a series of get/post requests for an application I'm making (a custom wrapper for an online chat). I completed the site login process and initial chat loading, by loosely simulating requests logged from *Telerik Fiddler*.

Now I'm having trouble with a different post request, that registers the user as online.

It's a connection to a socket.io server, but I know for a fact it's possible to do without a socket connection, because everything worked fine when I sent my requests with Fiddler's "composer" feature.

Here's the request I'm trying to simulate

```
POST http://events.********.com/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/vLaINOG3fKixnNs-oTWq?t=1498442322413 HTTP/1.1
Host: events.********.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 144
Origin: http://www.********.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://www.********.com/home.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

5:::{"name":"updateUserStatus","args":[{"status":"online"}]}
```

Here's how it looks trying to simulate it (ignore the different url, it should work with this)

```
POST http://events.********.com/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/owR02QZlrwKOwcLjoTW8 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: events.********.com
Content-Length: 60
Expect: 100-continue

5:::{"name":"updateUserStatus","args":[{"status":"online"}]}
```

Clearly a lot of stuff missing, but I don't think most of it matters. What I've noticed is that the original request's header has content-type set to "text/plain," and even though I've tried many ways to change the accept and content-type headers to match, it always sends as application/json and results in a 404.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1aIe.png)

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious and stupid, but I've been troubleshooting for the past couple hours and can't figure anything out.

Here's the code I'm using for the request (I took out the "text/plain" content-type and other stuff i had before that didnt work so it's somewhat cleaner)

```
chatreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://events.********.com/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/" + socket);
chatreq.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
postData = "5:::{\"name\":\"updateUserStatus\",\"args\":[{\"status\":\"online\"}]}";
data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
chatreq.Method = "POST";
chatreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
chatreq.ContentLength = data.Length;
using (var stream = chatreq.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
response = (HttpWebResponse)chatreq.GetResponse();
```

Or, if there's a simple way to send a raw http request, that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `WebClient.UploadValues'. It is one of the simplest way to post to an URL (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900ted1f(v=vs.110).aspx). Related SO pos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post

Comment: If you're setting content type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" how can it be "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" ?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar Like I said, that snippet is how it is before. I've already tried changing it to text/plain, and it still goes through as application/json. It's probably automatically doing it because the post data is json (with the weird 5::: thing taken off anyway)

Comment: @Subbu I've tried one other way to send it, I don't remember if that's it, but I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Headers.Clear()` first, and then set all the headers, and it went through normally.

I ended up using a socket.io library for this project though, since it ended up being a lot easier.